# Matlab's sort function in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, sorting, indexing

Let´s say that i have a matrix `a` in matlab and a vector `b` as follows:

```
a =
     2     1     1
     3     3     1
     3     2     2

b =
     1     3     2
```

Using matlab´s `sort` function I can achieve the following:

```
[n idx] = sort(b)

n =
     1     2     3

idx =
     1     3     2

anew = a(idx,idx)

anew =

     2     1     1
     3     2     2
     3     1     3
```

**Now, I want to do exactly the same in python. My attempt:**

```
a = np.array([[2,1,1],[3,3,1],[3,2,2]])

b = [0,2,1]

idx = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(b), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to build the `anew` matrix as I did using Matlab. I have tried:

```
anew=a[idx]

anew

array([[2, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 1]])
```

As you can see the results (matlab vs python) are not the same.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` has advanced indexing, so directly use `idx` on both dimension will trigger advanced indexing and the result will be a 1d array; To index in a cross product fashion, you'll need to use `np.ix_` to construct the index mesh, as stated from the docs:

> Using `ix_` one can quickly construct index arrays that will index the
>   cross product.

```
a[np.ix_(idx, idx)]

#array([[2, 1, 1],
#       [3, 2, 2],
#       [3, 1, 3]])
```

Or another option is slice in two steps:

```
a[idx][:,idx]
#array([[2, 1, 1],
#       [3, 2, 2],
#       [3, 1, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you I  really appreciate it